# How to update the Stripe Disputed Record Status

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hi I have a new dispute created at Stripe with the status **warning_needs_response**.
So I want to change this status with value **warning_under_review**.
I have this code

```
   $stripe->disputes->update(
  'du_1KDL6AAnDItLrqj23xPFWxoW',
   ['status' => 'warning_under_review']
  );
```

Display following error

```
       Fatal error:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_jLpvLCZQjoOadJ) Received unknown parameter: status
```

So how I can change the status please guide with thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you actually [update a dispute](https://stripe.com/docs/api/disputes/update) you can only change three parameters: `evidence`, `metadata` and `submit`.
In your case, you're receiving an inquiry which means that the status of your dispute would start as `warning_needs_response` and once you update your dispute and you submit it to the bank (`submit` field should be set to true, which is the default value) that value would change to `warning_needs_review` before either winning or losing the dispute.

In other words, you can't manually change the status of your dispute.

Answer (score 0):

We can update Evidence with following Stripe API code in PHP.

```
       $stripe->disputes->update(
          $test['id'],
          [
            'evidence' => [
              'access_activity_log' => $striplog,
              'product_description' =>$stripedescription,
              
            ],
          ]
        );
```